# "maven-cucmber-reporting" plug in could not be resolved. Not able generate the report as well. Cucmber,Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, report

I got the following plugin in my pom.xml but the maven-cucmber-reporting pluging is unable to generate the report. Also it shows "Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugins groupid,artifactid and version are present.

Could someone help me resolving this issue? or is the maven-cucumber-reporting jar is unavailable?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>execution</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectName>CucumberWebGui</projectName>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: [Looks fine to me](https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting), although `2.8.0` is five years old.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What could be the issue then? Why maven is failing to get the plugin? Could you please let me know which version you are using?               Just want to update I have other plugins as well along with this. .. surefire and maven compile

Comment: Are you still having the problem? Are you able to download other dependencies? Did you run with `-X` to see if you're getting network errors?

Comment: Do we need any dependency for this plugin to run? I just have others like testng selenium and cucumber.

Comment: You do not need any other plugin although you should be able to connect to the maven repository for maven to work. If your network uses some proxy then you need to specify host and port in the settings.xml file. Let me know if you need a sample